# Set data in expandable listview android form JSON format

Tags: android, json, expandablelistview

I have following pattern of `JSON`

```
{
"menu": [{
    "id": "74",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "title": "Mobiles & Tablets",
    "menu_type": "7",
    "menu_icon_image": "",
    "link": "#",
    "childs": [{
        "id": "75",
        "parent_id": "74",
        "title": "Mobile Phones",
        "menu_type": "7",
        "menu_icon_image": "",
        "link": "categories/mobile-tablets"
    }, {
        "id": "76",
        "parent_id": "74",
        "title": "Mobile Accessories",
        "menu_type": "7",
        "menu_icon_image": "",
        "link": "#"
    }, {
        "id": "77",
        "parent_id": "74",
        "title": "Tablets",
        "menu_type": "7",
        "menu_icon_image": "",
        "link": "#"
    }, {
        "id": "78",
        "parent_id": "74",
        "title": "Audio & Video",
        "menu_type": "7",
        "menu_icon_image": "",
        "link": "#"
    }, {
        "id": "79",
        "parent_id": "74",
        "title": "Laptops",
        "menu_type": "7",
        "menu_icon_image": "",
        "link": "#"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "80",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "title": "WOMEN",
    "menu_type": "7",
    "menu_icon_image": "",
    "link": "#",
    "childs": [{
        "id": "81",
        "parent_id": "80",
        "title": "GIRLS CLOTHING",
        "menu_type": "7",
        "menu_icon_image": "",
        "link": "categories/womens-clothing"
    }]
}],
"slider": [{
    "id": "56",
    "url": "#",
    "default_image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/atbdev/cache/advertis_img/1-fl-itwQr56f76f6df2bea.png/88e5b614324080684af061c510496d29",
    "title": "Mobile Test Slider",
    "image": null,
    "days": null
}, {
    "id": "55",
    "url": "#",
    "default_image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/atbdev/cache/advertis_img/1-fl-uIXFZ56f76efbcd627.png/e5a0e22dcb0de1007c88c16db1aebb7f",
    "title": "Mobile Test Slider",
    "image": null,
    "days": null
}, {
    "id": "52",
    "url": "#",
    "default_image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/atbdev/cache/advertis_img/1-fl-QULkY56f7719eb0915.png/a4d0065b56b57b7d01d44873bbdb1df8",
    "title": "Mobile Test Slider",
    "image": null,
    "days": null
}, {
    "id": "51",
    "url": "#",
    "default_image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/atbdev/cache/advertis_img/1-fl-L0ROK56f7716acccf0.png/e194ea4403c4b4b7e17f1fecfa329f22",
    "title": "Mobiles & Tablets",
    "image": null,
    "days": null
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "url": "",
    "default_image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/atbdev/cache/advertis_img/1-fl-qtvVk56f60fd0379b9.jpg/510c150029fd29d1d77b869d837b126e",
    "title": "Slider Add",
    "image": null,
    "days": null
}],
"advertise": [{
    "id": "54",
    "usrl": "categories/mobile-tablets",
    "default_image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/atbdev/cache/advertis_img/1-fl-IWkmH56f66a2b60bde.jpg/05571c3c78954e1a461b87bd62698273",
    "title": "Mobile phone home page advertise",
    "image": null,
    "days": null
}, {
    "id": "53",
    "usrl": "categories/mobile-tablets",
    "default_image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/atbdev/cache/advertis_img/3-fl-YK1pI56f5102a7237b.png/118b3074314006a62a7f10867a447be6",
    "title": "Mobile phone home page advertise",
    "image": null,
    "days": null
   }]

}



  List<ExpanTitelandTotal> result1111 = new ArrayList<ExpanTitelandTotal>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < menuArrayList.size(); i++) {
                        ExpanTitelandTotal mExpanTitelandTotal11 = new ExpanTitelandTotal();
                        mExpanTitelandTotal11.setTitle(menuArrayList.get(i).getTitle());
                        mExpanTitelandTotal11.setLink(menuArrayList.get(i).getLink());
                        mExpanTitelandTotal11.setId(Integer.parseInt(menuArrayList.get(i).getId()));
                        //result1111.add(mExpanTitelandTotal11);
                        if (mGetDrawerAndHome.getMenu().get(i).getChilds().size() > 0) {
                            mExpanTitelandTotal11.setIsMultiple(true);
                            Log.d("mGetDrawerAndHome.getMenu().get(i).getChilds().size() ",String .valueOf(mGetDrawerAndHome.getMenu().get(i).getChilds().size()));
                            for (int j = 0; j < mGetDrawerAndHome.getMenu().get(i).getChilds().size(); j++)
                            {
                                Log.d("Sub Menu", mGetDrawerAndHome.getMenu().get(i).getChilds().get(j).getTitle());

                                ExpanTitelandTotal mExpanTitelandTotal = new ExpanTitelandTotal();
                                mExpanTitelandTotal.setTitle(mGetDrawerAndHome.getMenu().get(i).getChilds().get(j).getTitle());
                                mExpanTitelandTotal.setLink(mGetDrawerAndHome.getMenu().get(i).getChilds().get(j).getLink());
                                mExpanTitelandTotal.setId(Integer.parseInt(mGetDrawerAndHome.getMenu().get(i).getChilds().get(j).getId()));
                                result1111.add(mExpanTitelandTotal);

                            }
                        } else {
                            mExpanTitelandTotal11.setIsMultiple(false);
                        }
                        mExpanTitelandTotal11.setItemList(result1111);
                        mArrayListExpanTitelandTotals.add(mExpanTitelandTotal11);
                    }


                    listAdapterTNA = new ExpandableListAdapterTNA(ActivityDrawer.this, mArrayListExpanTitelandTotals, mExpandableListView);
                    mExpandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapterTNA);
                    mExpandableListView.setIndicatorBounds(10, 80);
                    mExpandableListView.setDivider(null);
```

above is my code and when i run this i get following output
[image]

In expandable list view two different category data store in all main category data ? any idea how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new List object inside the first for loop sentence:

```
List<ExpanTitelandTotal> result1111;

for (int i = 0; i < menuArrayList.size(); i++) {

result1111 = new ArrayList<ExpanTitelandTotal>();

/////YOUR CODE

}
```